# Creating Membership Directory using Views in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, directory

I was trying to create a membership directory view in Drupal 7 but came across this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'egyptia2_ess.droe_civicrm_membership' doesn't exist
```

I created the view and selected Show CiviCRM Memberships for the Content, and then after clicked continue and edit, it gave me the above error.

Double checking, I don't see that table in my MySQL database and am curious if there something I have to activate first prior to creating a view such as this one...

I'd appreciate any help - Matt

Comment: Note this is only an issue if you have Drupal and CiviCRM in two separate databases - and is one big advantage for Views builders for having them in a single database. You may also notice that the Views will have problems after an upgrade until you do an extra 'clear cache' in Drupal

Comment: @petednz-fuzion - Actually, I'm receiving this error while both Drupal and CiviCRM are in the same database, and I can only confirm this because it is the only database on my server (and the settings references as well...) - Could you see any other causes for this error?

Comment: We often find we have to do an extra Clear Cache in Drupal after a civi upgrade as mentioned on my previous comment. have you tried that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have separate databases then you need to enable CiviCRM Drupal views integration you need to add some information to the sites settings.php file.

Visit - /civicrm/admin/setting/uf?reset=1

Data from the above CiviCRM page needs to be copied and pasted into your sites settings.php file.

Detailed info can be found [here](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/integration/drupal/views/#drupal-7)